# Split a column with quotes and commas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe that consists of lines that look like:

> "{'displayName':'MartinscroftTramStop','locationIdentifier':'STATION^15306','normalisedSearchTerm':'MARTINSCROFTTRAMSTOP'}"

How do I split this into columns. I've tried str.slice[stop and start].

I suspect it's all the quotes but finding and replacing them don't seem to work either

Comment: You forgot to add a tag for the language you're coding in, which would help you get help much more quickly. You should [edit] to add that tag.

Comment: Where did this data come from?  You should fix it before you create a dataframe.  That's the string representation of a Python dict.  If you started with a dict, then unpack it before giving it to pandas.

Comment: You have two problems. The first one is that your data is just one big string (it is inside the quotes "). And the dict structure is not the most desired to create dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the first problem, the string object, using the `eval('..')` function. It will return the execution of the string, so will return the dict itself.

The second one, the dict structure, you have multiple choices. There is one solution

```
import pandas as pd
# Transform the string in dict 
dict_data=eval("{'displayName':'MartinscroftTramStop','locationIdentifier':'STATION^15306','normalisedSearchTerm':'MARTINSCROFTTRAMSTOP'}")

# Organize the data
columns_name = dict_data.keys()
data_list = [list(dict_data.values())]  # a row must be a list inside a list

pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=columns_name)
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue I have is that it's not just a single string, but a whole df of similar formatted strings. So 20 rows, with different variables.